# Problem with function triggered by OnFormSubmit when multiple are submited at once to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google Script function that works as expected however when receiving many form submissions at once I run into a problem when the data is copied.

If data comes in fast enough the wrong information may be copied to the other sheet.

Here is an example set. I submitted 4 form's at once and the data came in just fine.
[image]

However when the scrip ran that was triggered by the `OnFormSubmit` it managed to copy one of the rows of data twice overwriting another.

As you can see below the data `4` and `44` were coppied over twice and is missing the `2` and `22` data.

[image]

So with that my question is this:

Is there a way to prevent this kind of duplication of information. Some way to Q up the function if one is already running?

Here is the code:

```
function Auto_move_form_data() {
  var form_name = "Form Responses 1";
  var open_name = "OPEN";

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(form_name);
  var open_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(open_name);

  var form_last_row = form_ws.getLastRow()
  var open_last_row = open_ws.getLastRow()

  form_ws.getRange(form_last_row,2).copyTo(open_ws.getRange(open_last_row+1,1), {contentsOnly:true});
  form_ws.getRange(form_last_row,3).copyTo(open_ws.getRange(open_last_row+1,3), {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you use the [event obj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to get the submitted data rather than going to the linked sheet and trying to copy the last row.

Comment: @Cooper how would that work? I am very new to google sheets and its functions/methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create an onFormSubmit trigger for the following function.

```
function Auto_move_form_data(e) {
  var dsh= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("OPEN");
  dsh.appendRow([e.values[2],'',e.values[3]]);
}
```

Comment: That appears to fix the problem I was having with duplicate data. And it is simpler than what I was doing. So I am guessing that this `(e)` is getting the event data from the form submit event as an array of data and we just use that array to append to the open page. Its good to know you can receive an event like this.

Comment: I also find it useful to actually look at "e" (the event object) like this `function onFormSubmitFunction(e) { Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))....` Often you will find data that is not documented and thus can save you time getting data that you might otherwise have to run a time consuming function to obtain.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I do something similar when inspecting tkinter events in python.